# How to make QR Page Footer or Band to be under Band Details not at the page end?

Tags: delphi, layout, report, quickreports

I need to make report, that has summary after Details had printed, not after every each Detail.

I only know the Page Footer, but it's at page bottom not after the Detail Band.

Is there a `QRBand` that could go after Detail Band?
Or can you make `PageFooter` height resize on every page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary Bands print only at the end of the report immediately after the last 'detail' (unless the `AlignToBottom` property is set to `true`).

You should add a `TQRBand` to the report and set the `BandType` property to `rbSummary`.

---

EDIT

If you need to show intermediate results on every page you could add the `FooterBand` **and** the `SummaryBand`.

[image]

Summary Bands prints only at the end of the report (last page) and you can use the `BeforePrint` event of the summary to disable the footer band.

---

EDIT2

You can also try with a `QRGroupBand` and a `QRFooterBand`.

In the `GroupBand`:

- use the `Expression` property for separating one group of products from another (the band could also be empty)
- set appropriately the `FooterBand` property. This is where you link the header band to the correct footer band and encapsulate your group inside. Place the header band first and then go back and place the footer band by dropping a `QRBand` component and immediately changing the `Type` from `rbTitle` to `rbGroupFooter`. Once you have done this, you can go back to the `QRGroup` header and select the right footer band to use.

The `FooterBand` is where you are printing summary totals for each product.

Comment: The rbSummary is only at last page not at every page

Comment: @manilo well it works, but only when there are millions of data just flowing in, but if the data is sorted and divided in each page, than it doesn't work. ex. sort by product, each page has it's own product by which it's sorted, then your solution doesn't work

Comment: @manilo could it actually be done by the `TQRWildBand` ? I know that `WildBand` can be printed any time but i don't get it how to make it print.

Comment: @qaetosh It seems that a `rbGroupFooter` could work (see the modified answer).

Comment: @qaetosh A `TQRWildBand` prints (once) whenever the `PrintNow` property is set to `true`. When it prints it resets the property to `false`.

Comment: @manilo big thanks i forgot that my header is a `QRGroup` element that it has 3 Linkages ans one of them is the `FooterBand`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem with the help of quickreport events and datasource events.
In a test project, it is enough to put a tqrlabel in the pagefooter, the rest is written below.

```
type
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ...
private
  firstValue: Integer;
public
  counter: Integer;
end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  PageSummery: Integer;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  adoquery.First;
  counter := 0;
  firstValue := adoquery.FieldByName('id').AsInteger;
  PageSummery := 0;
  Form2.QuickRep1.Preview;
  Form2.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.adoqueryAfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if counter <= 1 then
    PageSummery := firstValue + adoquery.FieldByName('id').AsInteger
  else
  begin
    PageSummery := PageSummery + adoquery.FieldByName('id').AsInteger;

    form2.QRLabel2.Caption := IntToStr(PageSummery - Form1.adoquery.FieldByName('id').AsInteger);
  end;
counter := counter + 1;
end;
```

Pay attention to the location of the variables in the first form.
The first button is used to fill the query data.
After each increase, the data is placed in the qrlabel so that all the data is saved when the event is triggered.
The final point is in the quickreport event, which occurs before filling the print rows when creating a new page. In this event, a number of variables must be set to zero.

```
procedure TForm2.QuickRep1StartPage(Sender: TCustomQuickRep);
begin
  if Form1.counter = 0 then
    PageSummery := 0
  else
    PageSummery := Form1.adoquery.FieldByName('id').AsInteger;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `GroupHeader` and a `GroupFooter` to the report. Make the Expression on the `GroupHeader` = `PAGENUMBER`, and set Height = 0; in it's `BeforePrint` event handler, so that it never shows. Set the `GroupHeader`'s `FooterBand` property to the `GroupFooter` band. Then put your page totals or whatever on the `GroupFooter`. This will print after the detail on every page, and the Summary will print after that on the last page!